# What's the Russian feminist position on (female) conscription?

Tags: russian-federation, public-opinion, feminism, conscription

In a fairly upvoted [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83473/18373) here, it's asserted that Russian feminists oppose female conscription, at least in the conception of one self-declared (Russian) anti-feminist.

Is it the case though that self-identified Russian feminists oppose female conscription (more than male conscription)? Are there any polls on self-identified Russian feminists on this matter?

---

Seeing the answer and one comment: I'm not asking strictly about 2022-2023. Polls before the full scale invasion of Ukraine would be fine too. I'm interested in the general position of Russian feminists on conscription. Admittedly, the war and laws related to that makes it more difficult to poll now.

Comment: Believable polls are in short supply in Russia, these days.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: come to think of it, I could probably [also] ask about other countries more easy to poll e.g. https://www.deseret.com/opinion/2021/8/3/22594821/im-a-feminist-a-mandatory-military-draft-would-be-terrible-for-our-women ; https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/apr/17/israel.gender

Comment: Seeing the edit since my answer, it may be helpful if you would be more specific about what you mean by "female conscription". The state may direct women's economic labour during war, and the military may call for women volunteers, but I'm not sure there is any example in history of them being "conscribed" into conventional combat - such that there could exist credible "feminists who oppose female conscription".

Answer (score 3):

Army draft is usually not in focus of Russian feminists, but if pressed they usually say that they are against army draft for all.

No feminist organization calls for conscription of females as army service is not considered prestigious in Russia.

One widespread point of Russian self-declared feminists is "we are for equal rights, not for equal duties", with all cases of discrimination of men in law they count as different duties (determined by the different physical abilities), not different rights, so, do not see anything bad with it.

For instance, a prominent Russian feminist blogger known as Morena Morana (33rd place in the Cyrillic LiveJournal) [says](https://morena-morana.livejournal.com/1220310.html) that she is for equal rights (because it is in the Constitution) but not for the equal duties because of the physical differences between sexes, and in the context of draft, compares women to the disabled men who are also exempt from service.

Comment: I removed a large part of this answer because it wasn't about the topic of feminism in Russia but a tangent on demands from various men's rights groups. Please remember to answer the question and only the question. The question is explicitly only about feminist positions on conscriptions. The positions of other political factions are irrelevant for this question. If you want to talk about the positions of men's rights groups on the issue of conscription (or any other issue), post a new question.

Comment: Permanent military employment is actually semi-prestigious in third tier cities since the pay is somewhat better than average. *Conscription* is basically unpaid servitude so it is obviously of low prestige. Though, you get a wage if you sign contract afterwards.

Comment: @alamar obviously, feminists are for the right of the women to go to a voluntary service (which was always available, even in Tsarist Russia). They are against the mandatory one.